# Paramater for name of a table without using prepare statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, parameters

can i somehow set parameter for name of table in query without using a prepare statement?

This is example:

```
SET @tableName = 'Customer';

SELECT * FROM @tableName;
```

Thanks

Comment: Not w/o using dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of MySQL you are using, you may be able to use something like:

```
SET @tableName = 'Customer';
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tableName);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```